# Expected value of Bernoulli with probability of success Gaussian distributed

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, expectation, neural-networks

I have a circle with centre $(0,0)$. I am generating Matlab code to include $N$ neurons in a neural network. The probability of including individual neurons in a network decays exponentially with distance, $d$, from the centre. So the probability of a neuron being included is Gaussian with distance, i.e. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-d^2/r^2}$, where $r$ is the radius of the Gaussian (I'm not dealing with truncated Gaussians at this point). Once the probability of including the neuron has been determined, I then generate a uniform random variable on $[0,1]$, & if the value is less than the bound given by the Gaussian probability it's included, otherwise it's not.

However, since I want the expected number of included neurons at the end of this process to be $N$, I need to scale the bound, but I am not sure how to do this to give a final value of $N$. It's complicated by the fact it's in multiple dimensions, but even starting with a single dimension would be great.

Sorry if this is confusing. I am happy to explain it in more detail if required. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: This question doesn't seem clear.  To say that the probability of success has a Gaussian distribution would appear to mean that the probability that that probability is between $a$ and $b$ is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_a^b e^{-d^2/r^2}\,\mathrm{d}d$.  But that doesn't make sense since it would mean it's just as likely that that probability is negative as that it is positive, and that is absurd since probabilities cannot be negative.${}\,\ldots\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots$ And it also yields a positive probability that the probability is more than $1$, which is also absurd (although if $r$ is small, that positive probability might be $0$ for practical purposes) (Besides $\displaystyle d\mapsto \frac 1{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-d^2/r^2}$ is not a probability density, although maybe that was a typo and $\displaystyle d\mapsto \frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-d^2/(2r^2)}$ was intended.)  Might it be that $\frac 1 {\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-d^2/r^2}$ was intended to be an actual probability rather than the value of a probability density? ${}\,\ldots\ldots\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: I believe that people doing simulation with the acceptance-rejection method often use gaussian shaped envelopes that are not necessarily probability density functions, and sometimes use 'probability' of generation in a proportional sense that does not require total probability 1 until a final adjustment later on..

Comment: @BruceTrumbo : Can you explain what the question is that is being asked here? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Simulate random observations from bivariate normal subject to some restrictions, using acceptance-rejection method. That is, generate 'candidates' in a convenient region, then use an acc-rej rule to get rid of candidates that don't meet restrictions. Metropolis-Hastings algorithm was the earliest (but not simplest) example of acc-rej method--used for Manhattan Project in mid-1940s. Some CS people speak 'probabilese' as a foreign language.See Wikipedia on 'gaussian function' and 'Metropolis-Hastings'.

Comment: Michael: thanks for your response. I have a Ph.D. in eng, not maths, so perhaps I'm missing some nuances of probability. If I am I'd love to improve my understanding. I believe $\operatorname{P}(a < X \le b)= F_X(b)-F_X(a)$, will be positive? Also, once scaled by $\delta d$ the probability will not be greater than 1 (important when discretising a continuous variable). I'm not sure what you mean by intended to be an actual probability rather than the value of a prob density? Do you mean the probability of a finite d rather than infinitesimally small d? (And yes, that factor of 2 was a typo.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Here is a one-dimensional version.
Make a sketch as follows: (a) Draw a standard normal curve (it has
height about .4 in the middle, inflection points at $\pm 1$,
and nearly touches the x-axis at $\pm 3.$
(b) Superimpose a rectangle with base extending between $\pm 2$
and 1 unit it height.

You will generate a candidate neuron randomly and uniformly
in the interval $(-2,2).$ At its location, draw a vertical line
up to the top of the box. You accept the candidate neuron precisely if a point at random on this line is beneath the normal curve.

If you want N accepted candidates, you need to generate M > N
candidates. You get M by multiplying N by the ratio of the
area of the box to the area under the curve within the box.

A program in R to do this is as follows. I picked N = 1000
and almost always get a number of accepted candidates within about 30
of 1000, usually much closer.

```
 a.gau = diff(pnorm(c(-b,b)))    # Area under Gaussian
 b = 2   # Box has base twice b  # Area of box 2*b
 N = 1000                        # Desired Nr. accepted
 M = N*2*b/a.gau                 # Candidates required
 x = runif(M, -b,b)              # Location of candidate    
 acc = (runif(M) < dnorm(x))     # M-vec has T if accepted
 x.acc = x[acc]                  # Retain accepted candidates
 length(x.acc)                   # actual number accepted
 hist(x.acc)                     # hist of accepted cand.
```

In the code 'runif(M, -b, b)' means pick M random points
between -b and b; 'runif(M)' means pick M random points between 0
and 1 (the default boundaries); and 'dnorm(x)' is the height
of the normal curve above point x.

You could get by with fewer candidate points if more are accepted.
It turns out you can double the height of the normal curve
and still be within the box. Modified code to do this is shown
below. (Altered lines have ##.)

```
 a.gau = diff(pnorm(c(-b,b)))    # Area under Gaussian
 b = 2   # Box has base twice b  # Area of box 2*b
 N = 1000                        # Desired Nr. accepted
 M = N*b/a.gau                   ## Candidates required
 x = runif(M, -b,b)              # Location of candidate    
 acc = (runif(M) < 2*dnorm(x))   ## M-vec has T if accepted
 x.acc = x[acc]                  # Retain accepted candidates
 length(x.acc)                   # actual number accepted
 hist(x.acc)                     # hist of accepted cand.
```

Note:  On the line, it would be easier just to sample directly
from the normal distribution. But I believe the acceptance-rejection
method with a gaussian envelope is better in 2-D. In 2-D you
will need x and y coordinates to pick candidate points. If this
is at all what you had in mind in your question, I suppose you
can adapt the idea of using ratios of areas to ratios of volumes
for your project.

Comment: Oh that's fantastic, thank you Bruce! I hadn't heard of rejection sampling before. What a versatile technique! And thank you very much to everyone who read & contributed to my question/thread. Bruce - if I wanted to discretise the locations in x, I assume that I would simply need to multiply the pdf by dx, the distance between the points, & the method would continue to work? Reading rejection sampling in wikipedia I can't see any reason why it wouldn't.

Comment: Not sure whether it works well for discrete distribution. I have never seen that kind of application. Don't see why not.

Comment: I just got it working with no problems at all for a general dx & dy (in 2D). Thanks again. I've never used one of these forums & now I'm a total convert!

Comment: Good to know you were able to extrapolate the idea to 2-D.